# How to prove $\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x} = \frac{\sec^2 x +2 \tan x}{2-\sec^2 x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been trying to prove this problem below using identities, but so far I haven't made much progress. I originally tried to use the fact that $\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x$ but I couldn't find my way forward.

$$\frac{1+\tan x}{1-\tan x} = \frac{\sec^2 x +2 \tan x}{2-\sec^2 x}$$

Comment: Did you try multiplying both top and bottom by $(1+\tan x)$?

Comment: Simplify the right side!

Comment: Or... If you make the replacement you suggested into the right side of the equation and factor a bit you should be able to move forward.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sec^2x + 2\tan x}{2 - \sec^2x} & = \frac{1 + \tan^2x + 2\tan x}{2 - (1 + \tan^2x)}\\
& = \frac{1 + 2\tan x + \tan^2x}{1 - \tan^2x}\\
& = \frac{(1 + \tan x)^2}{(1 + \tan x)(1 - \tan x)}\\
& = \frac{1 + \tan x}{1 - \tan x}
\end{align*}